# how to add uipickerview in uialertview swift 3

Tags: swift, popup, alert, uipickerview, uialertview

**Swift 3 iOS 10:** I want to add `UIPickerView` in `UIAlertView` so that i can choose item and set it's value to the textField. I could do it with `UIView` but I want to improve it in a better and natural way. Is it possible to do this or any way out?

Thank in advance!

This is what I have done,

**Pix1: my textfield**: https://z-p3-scontent.fpnh5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/19702221_1969127863363332_1282515913735651533_n.jpg?oh=ece774626e6691c531dc69b168104fcc&oe=59D72E14

**Pix2: my alert:** https://z-p3-scontent.fpnh5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/19665630_1969127860029999_9139151345242136168_n.jpg?oh=d56be1efc3bd772ff68e7e45fa7ebfae&oe=5A0F290F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Apple suggests us not to do so, you can indeed add a picker view to your alert view controller. `UIAlertViewController` has nothing magic other than a normal view controller. All you need to do is to show title text with lots of new lines (namely "Select\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n") in order to increase the alert height, and then call `alertViewController.addSubview(datePicker)`

However the questions is why you need to write extra code to manipulate an alert view controller and handle which text field to set value? Here is another approach that is way easier to maintain and implement.

First create your picker view and configure it.

```
let picker = UIPickerView()
picker.delegate = self
picker.dateSource = self
// configure
```

Then for each of your text field, simply call this

```
tf1.tag = 1
tf2.tag = 2
tf3.tag = 3

tf1.delegate = self
tf2.delegate = self
tf3.delegate = self

tf1.inputView = picker
tf2.inputView = picker
tf3.inputView = picker
```

Not in your text field delegate method, store which text field user clicked on and reload picker view data

```
var tfTag = 0

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    tfTag = textField.tag
    picker.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

Finally in all your picker view data source or delegate method, load different set of data base on the unique tag number from each of the text field

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if tfTag == 0 {
        if component == 0 {
            return "1"
        }else if component == 1 {
            return "2"
        }else if component == 2 {
            return "3"
        }else{
            return "4"
        }
    }else if tfTag == 1 {
        //...
    }else{
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i want. But i have one problem with this. I cant use uipickerview when I have multiple/many textfield

Comment: @EKChhuon Updated

Comment: So if you submit this to the appstore, do you think they would reject it?